# worklight project, windows 8 apps

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

i am trying to use C# connect to sqlite database and after that use the javascript to call the c# function to retrieve all the data. how can i connect the worklight project (javascript, generate from the worklight) with my c# in the windows 8 apps. please help

i find some of the example that require the implement this

```
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;
```

but i can't find the assembly reference for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not available for Worklight-based Windows 8 apps.

You can submit a feature request to have it considered for future releases of Worklight: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

However this may be possible by using the WinJS API: [Using SQLite in your Windows Store application](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2012/10/windows-8-using-sqlite-in-your-windows-store-application/#.VCPy9iuSzBc)